# Check if a time is between two other times including minutes

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, powerapps-forms, formula

I have a PowerApps form which contains an adjustable "Submission Date" field. Here is a screenshot to show what I mean:
[image]

I am trying to come up with a formula for a calculated column in SharePoint called "Submission Status" to determine whether or not the form was submitted during the day, which in my case would be between 9:30 AM to 5:00 PM (inclusive) on a weekday. I can get it to work for 9:00AM to 5:00PM, however I can't get it to work with a schedule starting at exactly 9:30AM. I'm fairly new to SharePoint so I'm not sure how to account for those minutes.

For reference, this is the formula I've got that works for 9:00AM - 5:00PM :

```
=IF(OR(HOUR([Submission Date])>17,HOUR([Submission Date])<9),"Submitted after hours",
IF(OR(TEXT([Submission Date],"dddd")="Saturday",TEXT([Submission Date],"dddd")="Sunday"),"Submitted on a weekend",
IF(OR(HOUR([Submission Date])<=17,HOUR([Submission Date])>=9),"Submitted during the day")))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use TEXT function like `TEXT([SubmissionDate], "hh:mm")` to accomplish this.

See the formula that worked for me. **Please update Column name in the formula with the one that is in your list**

```
=IF(OR(TEXT(SubmissionDate,"dddd")="Saturday",TEXT(SubmissionDate,"dddd")="Sunday"),"Submitted on a weekend",IF(AND(TEXT(SubmissionDate,"hh:mm")>="09:30:00",TEXT(SubmissionDate,"hh:mm")<="17:00"),"Submitted during the day","Submitted after hours"))
```

[image]